# when does a Makefile evaluates Eclipse's build variables?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, build, gnu-make

I'm working on a makefile C project using Eclipse as the IDE.

In the project properties (Project->C/C++ build->Environment) I added a variable, called "MY_VAR" and assign the value "some_str" to it.

at the head of my makefile I assign a value to some build variable using MY_VAR, like this (tried both "=" and ":=" assignments):

```
ANOTHER_VAR = $(MY_VAR)/another_str
```

ANOTHER_VAR gets the value "another_str" as if MY_VAR is empty.

however, when I print the values of the variables inside the rule's recipe, it prints the right value:

```
my_rule:
    @echo MY_VAR $(MY_VAR)
    @echo ANOTHER_VAR $(ANOTHER_VAR)
```

and it prints:

```
MY_VAR some_str
ANOTHER_VAR another_str
```

Question is why is MY_VAR seems to be empty in the variables declarations in the head of the makefile but does get the right value inside the rule recipe and how can I use the Exlipse defined variables at the variable declaration stage, before rules are executed?

Thanks.

Comment: There's something fishy with the output. `ANOTHER_VAR` should at least be `/another_str` (note the leading slash). As it isn't, either you didn't show us the right test output or we are looking at two different makefiles or irrelevant parts of the makefile.

Comment: I haven't copied the real output but I did notice what you said in the real output. don't know why I waived it but after your comment I came back to check a couple of things and then realized I made a really really stupid mistake. I included the wrong makfile and that caused the confusion.

is there a way to delete the question??? I don't want anybody to see how stupid I am :)